# Failed to execute goal while using Maven to install Accumulo

Tags: maven, ubuntu, accumulo

I am trying to install [Accumulo](https://accumulo.apache.org/). But I am running into an issue.

Here is the command that I am using:

```
mvn package install -X
```

Here is the last part of the execution of the installation where you can clearly see the error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Project ............................ SUCCESS [ 15.329 s]
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Fate ............................... SUCCESS [01:05 min]
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Start .............................. FAILURE [  7.833 s]
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Core ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Documentation ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Server Base ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Tracer Server ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Shell .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Simple Examples .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo GC Server .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Master Server ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Monitor Server ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Tablet Server ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo MiniCluster ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Native Libraries ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Proxy .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Iterator Test Harness .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Testing ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Accumulo Maven Plugin ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:30 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-26T15:05:30+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (Build Test jars) on project accumulo-start: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (Build Test jars) on project accumulo-start: Command execution failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:276)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:660)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:265)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :accumulo-start
```

Is there a package I am missing? Some bug with Ubuntu?

OS:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

I am using the current version of Accumulo ([the master on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/accumulo)).

Comment: Don't do `mvn package install`. That will execute half of the build twice. `install` includes all the steps in the maven lifecycle before it. Also, it's pretty unusual to use `install` at all. You probably want to just build (`package`) or run the full post-build verification steps (`verify`). See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's failing during the execution of the makeTestJars script, https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/master/start/src/test/shell/makeTestJars.sh, meaning that it can't find one of those four commands on your system (mkdir, sed, $JAVA_HOME/bin/javac, or $JAVA_HOME/bin/jar).

Comment: Yes with starting Hadoop I was thrown the error JAVA_HOME not set. The weird thing is that when I echo $JAVA_HOME I have the right value. I had to go in the Hadoop start bash script and change export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} to my value... And then Hadoop worked. But this is just for Hadoop. This solution might work also for Accumulo. But why is this happening when JAVA_HOME is set?

Comment: You have to make sure JAVA_HOME is set, and exported from your shell. A simple `export JAVA_HOME` should work if it's already set.

Comment: It is in my ~/.bashrc That's why I am a little confused. I actually added a export JAVA_HOME in makeTestJars.sh and it still does not work.